# Existing InfoPath form to Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, visual-studio, infopath

Can we convert existing InfoPath 2010 form to visual studio and make it applied to list? I am using SharePoint 2010 and InfoPath designer 2010. We have an existing InfoPath form used by a list in our SharePoint site and the user is looking for this change over.

Is it possible?If so can someone give suggestions or steps how to follow?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, depending on how you publish your InfoPath Form. Try publishing it as a Content type and then it becomes re-usable in one or many libraries. My blog here will help you http://www.legeris.net/blog/2016/1/31/5cis6ei4qmhxqd4sithfi9d2vrs7fi#PubCTDemo